# How can I call another extjs panel from my current panel?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have two Panels and I want to call one panel from the other one.  I would like to destroy the first panel and render the second panel right where the first panel was.  Is this the correct way to do that?

```
function create(){
  var testButton = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Switch panel',
    handler: function(){
      Ext.getCmp('backgroundForm').destroy();
      upload();
    }
  });

  var backgroundForm = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'backgroundForm',
    renderTo: 'mainPackage',
    autoHeight: true,
    buttons: [testButton]
  });
}

function upload(){
  var testButton = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Switch panel',
    handler: function(){
      alert('Test');
    }
  });

  var backgroundForm = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'newBackgroundForm',
    renderTo: 'mainPackage',
    autoHeight: true,
    button[newTestButton]
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you could of course put both panels in a card layout, or you could use panel.remove() and panel.add() to parent , to add and remove panels